# Fit on original data vs linear fit on transformed data

Tags: data-transformation, curve-fitting

I asked a question yesterday ([Better function to fit log-like data?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/643589/better-function-to-fit-log-like-data)) and the accepted answer got me thinking.

For non-linear data, Is it better/more recommended to asses the goodness of fit on the original data or on the transformed linear data?

Here's an example of what I mean using the data from my previous question. The $R^2$ metric says that the logit fit is better on the transformed data (top row), but the MSE says that the arctan fit is better on the original data (bottom row).

[image]

Comment: What does the $R^2$ say on the original data and the MSE say on the transformed data?

Comment: These are [related](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/32596/what-is-the-difference-between-coefficient-of-determination-and-mean-squared) but not identical fit statistics, your question seems to boil down to whether you want to use $R^2$ or $\text{MSE}$ to decide which is the best one.

Comment: The MSEs measure entirely different things and therefore are not suitable for comparison.  After all, if (say) the original variable is a length, then its arctangent is an angle, so you are comparing lengths to angles, which is nonsensical.  The $R^2$ are irrelevant, too, because they measure a combination of goodness of fit and *range* of the data, while the arctangent likely changed the ranges substantially.  Thus, you ought to be asking *how* to assess goodness of fit rather than asking which of two meaningless methods to choose from!